# How to use es2020 features in vue 2.6 project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-2020

I have a Vue 2.6 project and I want to use the es2020 characteristics like optional chaining in my project but I can't get it to work in my project. I'm getting the following error.

```
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                           12:59:10

 error  in ./src/components/list/columns/lastUpdate.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (15:20)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|       if (!this.data.ObjInst || !this.data.ObjInst.Last_Update) return '';
| 
>       if (this.data?.ObjInst) {
|         console.log("Hello");
|       }

 @ ./src/components/list/columns/lastUpdate.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 1:0-349 1:365-368 1:370-716 1:370-716
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.0.21:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

I have installed babel pluging but I'm getting the same error.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining
```

I have been googling but I have not found any info about it.

These are my project's dependencies

```json
{
...
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.24.2",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
    "vue2-admin-lte": "^0.4.3",
    "vue2-daterange-picker": "^0.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.12.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "^0.6.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  }
...
}
```

Please, help me!

Comment: Installing `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining` doesn't help anything as this doesn't affect whether it's used or not. See https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#babel and https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/babel-preset-app#babelpreset-env . I wouldn't expect problems in default Vue CLI config, so the problem may be specific to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so you can achieve that, unless you will implement it by yourself. ES2020 features such an optional chaining are available in `Vue 3`, but not `Vue 2.x`.

[More information can be found here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/11088)

**UPDATE 20.07.2023**

From comment below (@DMack):

> For anyone finding this question post-2.7, this should be a non-issue now. From the 2.7 release notes: [Vue 2.7] supports using ESNext syntax in template expressions. When using a build system, the compiled template render function will go through the same loaders / plugins configured for normal JavaScript. This means if you have configured Babel for .js files, it will also apply to the expressions in your SFC templates.

Comment: This is not true. The issue applies only to Vue templates because they are compiled differently than `<script>` part. The question explicitly lists the code that is not a part of a template.

Comment: @ulou thank you so much. I didn't know templates are compiled in a different way. Interesting.

Comment: @EstusFlask, You are right that code rendered in the HTML is limited, but OP has some script, so it's irrelevant

Comment: For anyone finding this question post-2.7, this should be a non-issue now. From the 2.7 release notes: [Vue 2.7] supports using ESNext syntax in template expressions. When using a build system, the compiled template render function will go through the same loaders / plugins configured for normal JavaScript. This means if you have configured Babel for .js files, it will also apply to the expressions in your SFC templates.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this is because the standard setup for Vue projects uses Babel/Webpack to transpile code into something that can be run in the browser (i.e., Vue templates to render functions) and add polyfills for newer features for backwards compatibility. Vue 2 uses Babel 6/Webpack 4, and they moved to Babel 7/Webpack 5 in Vue 3.

[@vue/cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/) currently has a beta version out that manages the upgrades to Babel/Webpack, but it may require you to rewrite some configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As @aweston mentioned, this is because of Webpack.

Optional-chaining entered not so long time ago [to Acorn](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn/pull/891), and Webpack (which depends on it) supports it only since ver. 5 (which is available in @vue/cli ver. 5, still in beta).

**You can use it in webpack ver. 4 as well**, but be prepared to tweak some babel in your project (it's not difficult!)

You should further read [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1697) in github assigning exactly your problem

Answer (score 0):

@Loop, add the below webpack object (chainedWebpack) in the vue.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {  
 chainWebpack: config => {
  config.module
  .rule('vue')
  .test(/\.vue$/)
  .use('vue-loader')
    .loader('vue-loader')
    .tap(options => {
      // modify the options...
      return options
    })
  .end()
  .use('vue-style-loader')
  .loader('vue-style-loader')
  .end()
 }
}
```

Do let me know if it works for you.